# Is Realm compatible with React Native 0.29?

Tags: react-native, realm

Updating to React Native involves changing the application template as described in the release notes here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.29.0

I have followed those instructions, but am unable to start the app (even after complete remove and reinstall). Get the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > A problem occurred configuring project ':realm'.
>   >     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':realm:_debugCompile'.
>   >     Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.

Is this my mistake somewhere, or is Realm not compatible with React Native 0.29? I note in the release notes they mention

> Plugins which pass activity reference in the constructor need to be updated to extend ReactContextBaseJavaModule use getCurrentActivity to get the activity reference. This change is backward compatible.

Comment: I got the same issues using React-Native 0.23.1. We found out that the issues are depending on the debugger you are using. Maybe you have some proxy behind or your both devices are not in the same network. Our solution was to enable the DEV-Settings. -> And from now using the "android-monitor" to compile (https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html).
I´d like to get a full answer if it is possible to fix this. But this was our solution till now.

Comment: Strange though, because we've come through several versions of RN just fine, and at some stage we were running okay with 0.23.x. Will try the things you've suggested!

Answer (score 3):

I just needed to update my Android SDK - no compatability issues with Realm and RN 0.29!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!